# How can I find number of GROUP of consecutive 1s in a binary number

Tags: python, pandas, binary

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains 1s and 0s in its rows. I want to count the number of group of consecutive 1s in my DataFrame. I repeat I am not asking for number of consecutive 1s, there are lots of examples on the web about it.

To be more exact:

Lets say the row of my pd.DataFrame is:

```
index value
0  0
1  1
2  1
3  0
4  0
5  1
6  0
7  1
8  0
9  1
```

I want output to be 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [itertools.**groupby**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = {'value': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   value
0      0
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      0
5      1
6      0
7      1
8      0
9      1
>>> sum(k for k, _ in groupby(df['value'])) 
4
```

Alternatively, if the key can be something other than `0`/`1` or you want to be more explicit:

```
>>> sum(1 for k, _ in groupby(df['value']) if k == 1)
4
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It exactly works as it is intended

Comment: It would be great if you could also explain what does the line of code does. I am little bit new to Python and syntax that you use is little bit foreign to me..

Comment: I used something called a comprehension, the [docs do a much better job explaining what they are than I could](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Similarly, make sure to click on the `itertools.groupby` link above. Finally if that doesn't help you could also search on YouTube/Google/DuckDuckGo/Bing for more resources/explanations.

Answer (score 2):

try:

Only works when you don't have 1 at the begiining or the end.

```
df['value'].diff().eq(1).sum()
```

add 0 on top and the bottom of the series:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series([0]), df.value, pd.Series([0])]).diff().eq(1).sum()
```

---

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the value into list , and then do the following:
This is from the top of my head you can probably find more efficient ways to do it

```
Countconsecutiveone=0
i=0
prv_is_one=0
While i<len(Newlist):
 if Newlist[i]==1 and prv_is_one==0:
       Countconsecutiveone+=1
       prv_is_one=1
 elif Newlist[i]==0 and prv_is_one==1:
           prv_is_one=0
 i+=1
```